# Error using bitxor in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working on a code in matlab, Here is a module which is creating problem, as follows:

```
    sum1=0 ;
    sum2=0 ;     
    for i=1:8
        sum1=sum1+w1(i)*(2^(i-1));
    end
    for i=1:8
        sum2=sum2+w2(i)*(2^(i-1));
    end
    sum1=floor(sum1);
    sum2=floor(sum2);
    z8=floor(z8);
    l1=bitxor(sum2,z8);
    l2=bitxor(sum1,z8);
```

Here z8 and w1(i),w2(i) are integer elements.
Whenever I compile i get a regular error

"Error using bitxor
Double inputs must have integer values in
the range of ASSUMEDTYPE."

I saw the documentation and tried adding ASSUMEDTYPE as

Comment: What did you add as `ASSUMEDTYPE` ? What was the outcome ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reconstruct your error.  Placing in dummy values for `w1`, `w2` and `z8`, the code works.  Therefore, what I can suggest is to check for the following things:

1. You must make sure that the inputs into `bitxor` are **non-negative** and they must have values that are less than or equal to `2^64 - 1`.  Check `sum1, sum2` and `z8` and ensure this is the case.
2. Make sure `w1` and `w2` **only contain** values of either 0 or 1.  What you are doing in `sum1` and `sum2` is reconstructing the base-10 representation of an 8-bit unsigned number.
3. Because this looks like 8-bit unsigned integers, it may be prudent to call `bitxor` with an additional parameter `uint8` to enforce the conversion to be this type:

   ```
   l1 = bitxor(sum2, z8, 'uint8');
   l2 = bitxor(sum1, z8, 'uint8');
   ```

## Example run

```
w1 = [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0];
w2 = 1 - w;
z8 = 35;
```

Using the above and running your code, I get this for `l1` and `l2`:

```
>> l1

l1 =

   137

>> l2

l2 =

   118
```